# Single Blazor Client to multiple minimal Apis

Tags: asp.net, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

Over the years I've progressed towards the micro-component using a backing api for it to keep a SPA of large complexity to a small, easier to maintain (relatively speaking) and rapidly deploy updates.

I've been following Blazor and .Net 6 since its early previews but something has eluded me:

Having a Blazor Client that utilizes more than one *.Server project. I have a group of minimal apis that cohesively serve as a business domain so packing them in a solution for deployments make sense ie pub/sub in context mapping.

Is it accurate that the *.Server is a BFF and I should simply add regular old empty api projects then configure them for being minimal then make plain old http/grpc calls to them from the bff?

Comment: How did you eventually decide to implement this?